# LightSwitch PreprocessQuery not filtering

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-lightswitch

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {

        query = (from projectPart in ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()
                 where projectPart.Project.Id == projectId
                 select projectPart.Part).AsQueryable();

        var test = query.ToList();
    }
```

This code compiles seems to work... What I mean is when I set a breakpoint on the var test and check it, it has the correct(filtered) items but when I view the results on the screen it shows the entire list no filtering applied.

It should be as simple as this:

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> projectPartIds = new[] {1, 2, 3};

        query = from part in query
                where projectPartIds.Contains(part.Id)
                select part;
    }
```

But when I do this LightSwitch throws an error that reads:

Not Implemented Inner exception message: The  method 'Contains' is not supported.

This on the other hand works perfectly but doesn't help me:

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        query = from part in query
                where (part.Id == 1 || part.Id == 2 || part.Id == 3)
                select part;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Per suggestion I also tried it like this:

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

        query = from part in query
                where projectPartIds.Contains(part.Id)
                select part;
    }
```

But then I get this error:
Not Implemented Inner exception message: The expression value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]).Conta‌​ins([10007].Id) is not supported

**EDIT 2:**

Here's list of things I tried and their respective errors:

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};

        query = from part in query
                where projectPartIds.All(x => x != part.Id)
                select part;
    }
```

ERROR: The method All is not supported when the MaxProtocolVersion is lass than 3.0

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        query = query.Where(x => projectPartIds.Contains(x.Id));
    }
```

ERROR: The method contains in not supported

```
    //I forgot to save the code for this example...
```

ERROR: Join Not Supported

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        IQueryable<Part> qTest = null;
        foreach (var partId in projectPartIds)
        {
            if (qTest == null)
            {
                qTest = from part in query
                        where part.Id != partId
                        select part;
            }
            else
            {
                qTest = (from part in query
                         where part.Id != partId
                         select part)
                    .Union(
                        from part in qTest
                        select part
                    );
            }
        }
        query = qTest;
    }
```

ERROR: Union is not supported

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var q1 = from part in query
                 where part.Id == 1
                 select part;

        var q2 = from part in query
                 where part.Id == 2
                 select part;

        query = q1.Concat(q2);
    }
```

ERROR: The method Concat is not supported

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var temp = this.ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute().AsQueryable();
        query = from p in query
                from pp in temp
                where pp.Part.Id == p.Id
                select p;
    }
```

ERROR: Expression of type System.Linq.IQueryable[LightSwitchApplication.ProjectPart] cannot be used for return type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[LightSwitchApplication.Implementation.ProjectPart]

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = (from pp in ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()
                              where pp.Project.Id == projectId.Value
                              select pp.Part).AsQueryable();
        query = query.Intersect(projectPartIds);
    }
```

ERROR: The expression is not supported (Intersect).  Argument types do not match

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = (from pp in ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()
                              where pp.Project.Id == projectId
                              select pp.Part.Id).ToList();

        var tempQuery = query;
        foreach (var partId in projectPartIds)
        {
            tempQuery = from p in tempQuery
                        where p.Id != partId
                        select p;
        }

        query = query.Except(tempQuery);
    }
```

ERROR: The method Except is not supported

*Final Notes (Update 2):*

I did find one thing that works and it's good enough for the demo on friday where I will only have 10 Parts but it is unacceptable because I don't believe that it is able to scale when I have 500k Parts.  Here's the code just in case it gives anyone an idea I haven't tried:

```
    partial void PartsInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? projectId, ref IQueryable<Part> query)
    {
        var projectPartIds = (from pp in ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()
                              where pp.Project.Id == projectId
                              select pp.Part.Id).ToList();

        var allPartIds = (from p in Parts.GetQuery().Execute()
                          select p.Id).ToList();

        var nonProjectPartIds = allPartIds.Except(projectPartIds).ToList();

        foreach (var partId in nonProjectPartIds)
        {
            query = from p in query
                    where p.Id != partId
                    select p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) in your first code block the source of data is `ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()` and other two you get data from ref variable `query` - which one is the correct source of data? 
(2) Also do you want to use `int? projectId` input? because it seems that you want to also use a `Contains` from a list of projects ids.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I really want a list of parts from the ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute().  If I had to I could get that as a list of Ids and I could use it to filter the query but apparently I can't use contains so that won't work either.

Comment: Can you post your definition of `Part` class

Comment: see my EDIT3 in the answer. Looks that your provider is not supporting Contains.

Answer (score 0):

To use `Contains` define your `projectPartIds` as a `List<int>`.
This compiles and runs OK:

```
public static void test4()
{
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 1 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 2 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 10 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 11 });
    var query = parts.AsQueryable();

    List<int> projectPartIds = new List<int>(new []{ 1, 2, 3 });

    var results  = from part in query
            where projectPartIds.Contains(part.Id)
            select part;
    foreach (var res in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result="+res.Id);
    }
}
public class Part
{
    public int Id;
}
```

just tested it and here is the output, no exceptions:

[image]

**EDIT2**

even this works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test5();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void test5()
{
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 1 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 2 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 10 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 11 });
    var query = parts.AsQueryable();

    test4(ref query);
}
public static void test4(ref IQueryable<Part> query)
{

    List<int> projectPartIds = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };

    query  = from part in query
            where projectPartIds.Contains(part.Id)
            select part;

    foreach (var res in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result="+res.Id);
    }
}
```

makes same output as above.

**EDIT 3**

I am suspecting that your `Query` provider (implementation in `ProjectParts.GetQuery().Execute()`) does not support `List<>.Contains`, in that case best is to `ToList()` your query results and then extract the prepared result into another query object and then use that. Otherwise modifying the original query is bound to problems:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test5();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void test5()
{
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 1 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 2 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 10 });
    parts.Add(new Part() { Id = 11 });
    var query = parts.AsQueryable();

    IQueryable<Part> preparedQuery;
    test6(query, out preparedQuery);  // results are output into preparedQuery

    foreach (var res in preparedQuery)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result=" + res.Id);
    }
}

public static void test6(IQueryable<Part> origQuery, out IQueryable<Part> preparedQuery)
{

    List<int> projectPartIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    var queryList = origQuery.ToList(); // convert to list to get a working Contains

    preparedQuery = (from part in queryList
            where projectPartIds.Contains(part.Id)
            select part).AsQueryable();

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either...
Not Implemented
Inner exception message:
The expression value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]).Contains([10007].Id) is not supported.

Comment: Please see the edit above to see if I did something wrong.

Comment: using `List<int> projectPartIds = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };` in my code works the same.

Comment: I didn't try your update 3 yet... as you can see from my update 2 I've tried quite a few things today.  I think your Edit 3 may be on to something... unfortunately I need to step away from this problem and address another more pressing one.  I'll be back on this Friday or Monday.  Thanks for all the help I'll get back to this as soon as I can.  Please see my Edit 2 to see where I'm at and if you have any additional comment's I'll check back in a couple days.